# Remember Me does not work in dialog login popup

Tags: asp.net, authentication, asp.net-mvc-4, modal-dialog, httpcookie

I am using MVC4 - razor engine. I am displaying login view using a modal dialog nd in the controller I am using "FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.UserName, model.RememberMe)" for setting the cookie. When I login directly using the page '/Account/LogOn', everything works fine and the username/password field get populated correctly if the use selects Remember Me option. But when I use the modal dialog to display the login view, it doesnt work and username/password doesnt get filled in from the cookie.

Please let me know how to resolve this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You appear to be confused: the "Remember me" checkbox does not refer to the username and password fields being automatically filled-in, but actually refers to the authentication cookie's lifespan: by default the cookie will expire when the user closes the browser window (causing them to re-enter their details). When this option is selected the authentication cookie will be persistent and the user will remain logged-in between different browser sessions.

A user's username and password are automatically entered into the form fields when supported by the browser, it is not a feature of the web application (it's also impossible, as applications should never have access to a user's plain password, nor are they stored in the cookie). This is what the "Do you want Firefox to remember your username and password for this site?" prompt is for.

I will agree that the terminology is confusing - "Remember me" could refer to either the login details being remembered by the browser, or by the authentication cookie being persisted on the client. I think the correct solution is to change the language from "Remember me" to "Keep me logged-in on this computer". It's more verbose, but far more accurate.

Comment: Thanks for response. I agree 'Keep me logged-in' would be an appropriate verbose. The problem I am currently facing is FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie() doesnt work when I check 'Remember Me' on the Login popup. The popup is displayed using Jquery dialog. All the browsers support auto filling of username and  password for a normal login page. Only when its rendered as a popup, the fields come out blank.

Comment: Browsers only auto-populate fields on page load when the fields are present. Fields added, or shown after the page loads (such as in a jQuery popup) will not be populated. But again, **this has nothing to do with SetAuthCookie at all**.